# GROK parse failure for logstash

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I am trying to parse mongo logs using logstash from default mongo.log file.

this is my filter config :

```
filter {      
  grok {          
    match => ["message", "%{MONGO_SLOWQUERY}"]       
   }
}
```

I am getting `grokparsefailure` in this.

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: This really should be asked on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com) which is for questions and answers relating to administration and configuration of systems and services. StackOverflow is for :"programming" based questions, of which this is not. Please move your post to the appropriate site instead of posting here.

Answer (score 1):

the macro you used match this type of logs:

```
MONGO_LOG %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} \[%{WORD:component}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
MONGO_QUERY \{ (?<={ ).*(?= } ntoreturn:) \}
MONGO_SLOWQUERY %{WORD} %{MONGO_WORDDASH:database}\.%{MONGO_WORDDASH:collection} %{WORD}: %{MONGO_QUERY:query} %{WORD}:%{NONNEGINT:ntoreturn} %{WORD}:%{NONNEGINT:ntoskip} %{WORD}:%{NONNEGINT:nscanned}.*nreturned:%{NONNEGINT:nreturned}..+ (?<duration>[0-9]+)ms
MONGO_WORDDASH \b[\w-]+\b
MONGO3_SEVERITY \w
MONGO3_COMPONENT %{WORD}|-
MONGO3_LOG %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{MONGO3_SEVERITY:severity} %{MONGO3_COMPONENT:component}%{SPACE}(?:\[%{DATA:context}\])? %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

According to: [logstash-patterns-core](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/mongodb)

Probably your message doesn't fit the patterns.
You could try if your message fit, using the Grok Debugger: [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

Regards